# Does a cURL packet travel through the end users PC

Tags: php, security, curl, packet, packet-sniffers

Does a cURL packet travel through the end users PC (ie the client connecting to my webserver).

For example, if I use cURL to connect to "http://www.example.com/?username=admin&password=password", will the end user be able to see this with packet sniffing?

Comment: Are you asking if cURL uses the internet..? Why yes, it does.

Comment: No.  cURL is "Client URL" right.  If my webserver, using PHP, generates a cURL connection, does it connect through my webserver, or through the client (end user) connecting to my webserver

Comment: Side note, use "example.com" for example host names. It is actually set aside for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the cURL request is initiated from your web server, the client does not know about the requests occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Using "curl" on the server-side will not be sniffable by the user making the request.

On the other hand, if you're transferring anything sensitive, you should still be using encryption to prevent sniffing from any other third-party.

Comment: cURL uses libcurl, which is "http://curl.haxx.se/" and does not call itself Client URL.

Comment: In any case, the rest of the answer is valid for the original question.